# How to retrieve  file content using full path?

Tags: android, download, filenotfoundexception

In Android webview, you could pass something like this `file:///android_asset/myfile.txt` or this `http://www.mysite.com/t.html` and it will get it without a problem. Now if I tried the first url with the file prefix in a reader "FileReader" it will throw an exception that **File not found** although in WebView it work with no problem (why?)

What I want is to create a function that could take a file or http url and get the content html using the full path "file:/// ..." how could I do this without facing the file not found exception ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now if i tried the first url with the file prefix in a reader "FileReader" it will throw an exception that file not found although in WebView it work with no problem (why?)

Because "File Reader" does not have an asset named `/myfile.txt`, presumably. "File Reader" is somebody else's program, not yours, so `file:///android_asset/myfile.txt` refers to an asset in that other program, not yours.

> What i want is to create a function that could take a file or http url and get the content html using the full path "file:/// ..." how could i do this without facing the file not found exception ?

Have an asset named `/myfile.txt` in your app.

I have not tried using standard Java I/O (e.g., `File` objects) to read `file:///android_asset` paths. That might work. If not, use `startsWith()` to determine if the string begins with `file:///android_asset` -- if it does, trim that off and use the rest with `AssetManager` to read the asset.